# Python API: Transformation from `Bone` bind pose to `PoseBone` using SQT

Tags: python, animation, armature, bones, transforms

---

I am trying to understand the Blender Python API, more specifically `Bone` and `PoseBone` types and how they fit in with skeletal animation.

This is how I understand it so far:

The `Bone` type holds the transformation matrix from the bone's local space to its' parent object's space in its' `matrix_local` property.

There is one `PoseBone` for each `Bone` in a scene for each frame of an animation. Another way to put it is: There is a pose for each frame of the animation and this pose's skeleton (for the current frame) is made up of `PoseBone` objects.

Each `PoseBone` holds the transformation matrix to transform the position of the bone in its' bind pose to it's position in the current frame. This transformation can be accessed through the `scale`, `rotation_quaternion` and `location` properties. If I apply these to the position of the bone in its' bind pose, then the bone will be moved to its' correct position for the current frame.

Each `Bone` has a `head` and a `tail`. As I understand it, the `head` is the origin of the bone's local coordinate space. So the "position" of the bone I mentioned earlier is also the position of the bone's `head`.

**Am I correct in my understanding so far?**

---

I am trying to create an animation system where the bone is initially in its' bind pose. There is a 4x4 transformation matrix to transform from object space to bone space. We use this to compute the origin/position of the bone in its' bind pose.

For each frame of the animation, the `scale`, `rotation_quaternion`, and `location` are used to transform the position of the bone from its' inverse bind pose to the pose in the current frame.

**One thing that is not clear to me is what the `rotation_quaternion` represents here. How do I use it to compute the position of the bone in the current frame?**

---

There is something else unclear to me. I understand that for skeletal animation in Blender, each vertex of a mesh has a list of bones that its' bound to, with an associated weight for each bone.

How is the final position of the vertex computed for each frame? Can I make a transformation matrix from the `scale`, `rotation_quaternion` and `location` properties, compute a weighted average of the matrices for each group, and use that to transform the vertex's position from its' bind pose? Again, I am not sure how to fit in the `rotation_quaternion` here.

As well, does the `tail` of the bone matter at all for the vertex skinning? As I understand it so far, all I need to know to compute the final position of the vertex for the frame are the SQT transforms of the relevant bones.

---

I am stuck on this and would appreciate someone helping me straighten this out. The documentation is appreciated but I think I am missing some essential details for what I need to do that I can't find in the documentation.

Partial answers and hints will still be appreciated.

Thanks,

YUNG PROGRAMMER

Answer (score 1):

using quaternion for rotation does prevent gimbal lock, see [Why are quaternions used for rotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919086/why-are-quaternions-used-for-rotations)

Use it to set the rotation part of your final matrix at time t. [See mathutils for conversion](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils)